How to copy images in a cell
I'm facing a problem that I don't know how I can interact with images inserted directly into a cell in Google Sheets. Conventionally, I paste a screenshot from the clipboard into a cell.
My task is to copy the entire table into a Google document. I'm using the below code. It works, but it ignores cells that have images in them.
function main(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("mysheet");
 const data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

  const folder_id = "FOLDER_ID";
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id);

  const doc = DocumentApp.create("KPI report");
  const id = doc.getId();

  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  file.moveTo(folder);

  const body = doc.getBody();
  body.appendTable(data);
}


The .getValue() method on a cell containing an image returns: CellImage.
.getImages() returns an empty array
.getValue() returns a string "CellImage"

How can I interact with these images and copy them into my Google Doc?

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A7108653+CellImage
